# Problema con codigo sencillo de C++

Tags: c++

el codigo debe analizar si es mayor o menor de edad, y arrojar un resultado en pantalla, pero da error.

```
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main ()

{
    int edad;
    cin >> edad ;
    cout << "ingrese su edad: " ;

    if (edad >=18)

{   
    printf << "usted es mayor de edad" << endl;
}

else

{
    printf << "usted es menor de edad" << endl;
}

system ("pause");
}
```

Comment: Cambia printf por cout

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Debes aclarar cual es el error que da.

Comment: ¿cual es el error?

Answer (score 3):

1) Existe una opción para agregar código.

2) Es muy útil si incluyes el error también.

Es muy probable que edad no estes guardando ningún valor a edad porque haces el cin antes del cout

ademas estas usando **printf** en vez de **cout**

printf usa una estructura como esta

```
 printf ("mensaje\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

bienvenido a Stack Overflow.

El error es que estás usando `printf` en lugar de `cout`.

`Printf`es una funcion heredada de C, así que dificilmente va asoportar la sobrecarga del operador de inserción.

Además, creo que primero debes imprimir el mensaje pidiendo la edad y luego leerla por teclado:

```
int edad;
cout << "ingrese su edad:"; 
cin >> edad ;
```

Comment: Te faltaría indicar que `printf` es una función heredada de C, por lo que dificilmente va a soportar la sobrecarga del operador de inserción. Así explicas el motivo por el que falla la compilación

Answer (score 1):

Te falto tu return 0; también podrías incluir #include  y quitar stdio.h, cuida la sintaxis de tu código, ya en comentarios anteriores te dijerón sobre usar cout.

Answer (score 1):

Hay 2 errores básicamente, el primero es que estás usando el cin antes de cout, es decir, primero lees el valor que se le dará a la variable edad y luego lo imprimes, cuando lo útil será solicitar el valor primero.

El segundo error es el uso de printf con sintaxis de cout de esta manera:

```
printf << "usted es menor de edad" << endl;
```

puedes usar:

```
cout << "usted es menor de edad" << endl;
```